# Read program output from stdin instead of using spawn

Tags: shell, expect

I'm trying to write a shell function that spawns a ssh process and authentificates with a password. Then, I'd like to use the spawned process to do further stuff with expect.

Here's the function I have so far:

```
ssh_cmd() {
    ssh $USER@$HOST 2>&1 | expect -c "
        log_user 0
        set timeout 5
        expect password: {
            send \"$PASS\n\"
            sleep 2
            log_user 1
        }
    "
}
```

And then I'd like to use given function in other places to interact with the ssh process like this:

```
ssh_cmd | expect -c "
    expect '#' {
        send pwd\n
        send exit\n
    }
    expect eof
"
```

However, running the `ssh_cmd` function with `-d` option for expect I get the following result:

```
expect version 5.45.4

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp0) match glob pattern "password:"? no
ubnt@ui1's password: expect: timed out
```

From what I understand, the output of `ssh` does not get piped correctly. I know the common way to do this would be to use `spawn`, but that would mean the process would get killed after expect exits and I could not have a generic function that authentificates ssh sessions and keeps the process alive for further usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're designing won't work. Expect needs the process to be spawned from within the `expect` interpreter using the `spawn` command. Passing the command's stdout into expect is insufficient.

You could try this:

```sh
ssh_cmd() {
    # a default bit of code if user does not provide one.
    # you probably want some checking and emit an error message.
    local user_code=${1:-set timeout 1; send "exit\r"; expect eof}
    expect -c "
        log_user 0
        set timeout 5
        spawn ssh -l $USER $HOST
        expect password: {
            send \"$PASS\n\"
            sleep 2
            log_user 1
        }
        $user_code
    "
}
```

and then invoke it like:

```sh
ssh_cmd '
    expect "#" {
        send pwd\r
        send exit\r
    }
    expect eof
'
```

Note that single quotes have no special meaning in expect, they are just plain characters: you probably don't want to expect the prompt to be the 3 character pattern <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>